# Why is date function returning wrong d of week?

Tags: php

This code:

```
$today = date('Y-m-d');<br>
$dayofweek = date("l", $today);<br>
$day_index = date("N", $today);<br>
echo $today;<br>
echo $dayofweek;<br>
echo $day_index;
```

(that is the entire code in the file).

Results in:

```
2019-11-24
Thursday
4
```

Today is indeed November 24, 2019, but it is Sunday, not Thursday! For the life of me I cannot figure out why it is doing this. (Yesterday, it said the day of the week was Wednesday instead of Saturday, as well).

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you passing a string (`$today`) to the `date()` function in the second parameter¿

Comment: The second parameter of `date` is a timestamp, not a string. Please read the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Date()` method expects the second parameter to be a timestamp as documented [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

> date ( string $format [, int $timestamp = time() ] ) : string

Try:

```
$todayTimestamp = time();
$today = date('Y-m-d', $todayTimestamp);
$dayofweek = date("l", $todayTimestamp);
$day_index = date("N", $todayTimestamp);
echo $today;
echo $dayofweek;
echo $day_index;
```

Comment: also, if he's just fetching today's date no need for `$todayTimestamp` and 2nd parameter of the `date` function as it'll fetch "today" by itself.